# Regular expression for specific character start and end

Tags: android, regex, string

I am writing regular expression for words which start with T and ends with A.

I write:-

```
^T\..*A$
```

But now I want to exclude the word `TEA`. How to exclude the specific word using the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your `^T\..*A$` regex matches a string that starts with `T.`, then has any 0+ chars other than line break chars (with `.*`) and then ends with `A`.

To match any string that starts with `T` and ends with `A` that is not equal to `TEA` you may use

```
(?s)^(?!TEA$)T.*A$
```

To make it case insensitive, add `i` modifier:

```
(?si)^(?!TEA$)T.*A$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dea2dQ/1).

**Details**

- `(?si)` - DOTALL (`s`) modifier to allow `.` to match any char and IGNORECASE (`i`) modifier to make the pattern case insensitive
- `^` - start of string
- `(?!TEA$)` - a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if the whole string is equal to `TEA`
- `T` - a `T`
- `.*` - 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `A` - `A` letter
- `$` - end of string.

Note that if you are using it in `matches()` method, the first `^` and last `$` can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find 'TEA' and 'TEEA' from this sample, 'TEA IS NOT TEEA'. You can try to use this regular expression.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((T|t)[A-Za-z]+(A|a))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("TEA or tea IS NOT TEEA or teea");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: I am working on regular expression for all words starting from `T` and ending with `A`. But `tea` word must be excluded.

Comment: @pkc456 I edited my answer. Please check this again.